# Insert Multiple lines to database

Tags: php, database, insert, line

I need insert multiple line from text area insert in to each row of database. but now is insert all line in one row how i can do it? also i want echo finished line, and echo if line exit with warning

My text area input is :

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
```

I want insert like this

```
id  url
1   line1
2   line2
3   line3
4   line4
5   line5
```

This is my insert.php

```
<html><body>
    <h1>indian mp3 Database: indianmp3</h1>

    <form action="post.php" method="post">
        Firstname:<textarea name="url" id="term" cols="40" rows="10"></textarea><br><br>
        Category: <select name="cat_id">
            <option value="1">cat1</option>
            <option value="2">cat2</option>
            <option value="3">cat3</option>
        </select>

        <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
</body></html>
```

This is my post.php

```
<html><body>
<?php
$host="localhost";
$user=" ";
$pass=" ";
$database=" ";
$con=mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die("Could not connect to host.");
mysql_set_charset('UTF8', $con);
if(!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: '.mysql_error());
}

if(isset($_POST['cat_id'])) {
    $cat_it=(int)$_POST['cat_id'];
    $url=$_POST[url];
    mysql_select_db($database, $con) or die("Could not find database.");
    $sql="INSERT INTO link (url, cat_id) VALUES ('$url' , '$cat_it')";
}
if(!mysql_query($sql, $con)) {
    die('Error: '.mysql_error());
}
echo "inserted all line";
mysql_close($con)
?>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Are you sure it's putting it as one line in the database? The problem may be with how you display it when you retrieve it later. If you're displaying it on a web page, you need to use `nl2br()` to convert the newlines to HTML `<br>` tags.

Comment: $url= nl2br($_POST[url]); i try this this one not work

Comment: I need insert every line as a separate row. i need post my database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem here is you are making single insert with entire `url data`.

**1)** first identify each url value from text area and make an array of it using explode with `'.'` or `specific keyword`.

**2)** loop through the size of url array to insert into the table.

while inserting check error on mysql object in error occurs exit otherwise keep on inserting till all insertion is done.

suppose you have all urls in  `$url= $_POST[url];` with `'\n'` seperate then:

```
$urlArr = explode("\n",$url);

for($i=0;$i< sizeof($urlArr);i++){
$sql="INSERT INTO link (url, cat_id) VALUES ('$url[i]' , '$cat_it')";
if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
                  {
                  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
                  }


}
```

and please start using `PDO or mysqli.`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `explode("\n", $url)`?

Comment: sir i have told what i expect.

Comment: Any one tell me how fix it?

Comment: i fund for($i=0;$i< sizeof($urlArr);$i++){ and $sql="INSERT INTO link (url) VALUES ('$urlArr[$i]' )";